# I cannot execute "make clean" in my terminal

Tags: c, makefile

Apologies for the inconvinience, it is my first time in stackoverflow.

I am trying to compile a make project, but when i do make clean, the terminal returns this error:

```
rm -rf build
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -rf build, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [nRF5_SDK_17.0.2_d674dde/components/toolchain/gcc/Makefile.common:79: clean] Error 2
```

in the makefile.common, line 70 i have this:

```
ifneq (,$(filter clean, $(MAKECMDGOALS)))

OTHER_GOALS := $(filter-out clean, $(MAKECMDGOALS))
ifneq (, $(OTHER_GOALS))
$(info Cannot make anything in parallel with "clean".)
$(info Execute "$(MAKE) clean \
  $(foreach goal, $(OTHER_GOALS),&& $(MAKE) $(goal))" instead.)
$(error Cannot continue)
else
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)  -> this is line 79
endif # ifneq(, $(OTHER_GOALS))

else # ifneq (,$(filter clean, $(MAKECMDGOALS)))
```

what can i do to solve this problem?

thankyou for your effort!

I tried to changle the output directoy.

Comment: What happens if you run that command manually?

Comment: I think you're mixing Windows tools and tools from a unix emulation environment (MSYS2, MSYS, Cygwin). Specifically, I think this is a Windows build of `make`, which doesn't know anything about your unix emulation environment and its `rm`.

Comment: First step is to create a [mre] which in this case likely would be `make clean:\n\trm -rf build` and see if you get the same error

Comment: @ikegami Probably it's unix build of `make` which has built-in `RM = rm -rf` but run under windows shell.

Comment: @dimich, A build made for one of these unix emulation environment wouldn't use a Windows shell. Wouldn't be a great emulation if it did.

Comment: This is not a C language question.  `Makefile` stuff should be asked under `makefile` tag, but is normally unrelated to C or C++ (or any other programming language)  Please take off the `C` tag.